# In TextView with marquee the doesn't start looping

Tags: android, marquee

I have one big layout and one dummy layout with just the text view in it. The text view widget in both cases is the same but when put in more complex layout it doesn't work.

Is there any restrictions for the marquee ?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="a sdasd as das d as d asd a sd as d a sd as d as das d a sd a" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case `android:focusable="true`" and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` makes test looping:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="some long text">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="a sdasd as das d as d asd a sd as d a sd as d as das d a sd a" >
        </TextView>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't not fixes the problem. In my dummy project everything works fine but when I put this textview widget in more complex layout structure then it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method to implement marque.This is working perfectly for me.

use this as textview

```
 <com.example.marque_test.marque_textView
        android:id="@+id/TV_FOOTER"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
           android:scrollHorizontally="true"
           android:text="a sdasd as das d as d asd a sd as d a sd as d as das d a sd a"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
```

marque_textView.java

```
public class marque_textView extends TextView
{
   public marque_textView(Context context)
   {
           super(context);
           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

   public marque_textView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle)
   {
   super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);

}
 public marque_textView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
   {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,Rect previouslyFocusedRect)
   {
       if (focused)
       {
           super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused)
   {
       if (focused)
       {
           super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isFocused()
   {
       return true;
   }
}
```